# PHP Upload Image fails with certain JPG files

Tags: php, html

I have written a form to upload an image and create a thumbnail, it checks to make sure image is JPG, PNG or GIF. It works in most cases but certain JPG files get called 'invalid file format'.

I tried reducing the resolution/file size with no luck but if I convert the file to .png it works fine.

Here is a link to a JPG that fails;
http://yourcomputerassistant.net/IMG0015.JPG

My code(I have removed the thumbnail creation to keep the question short);

```
  if(isset($_FILES["userimage"]) && $_FILES["userimage"]["error"] == 0){

      $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");

      $userimage = $_FILES["userimage"]["name"];
      $filetype = $_FILES["userimage"]["type"];
      $targetDir = "uploads/";
      $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $userimage;
      $targetThumbFilePath = "uploads/thumbs/";

      if(!file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["userimage"]["name"])){


      // Verify file extension
        $ext = pathinfo($userimage, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) {

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userimage"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
              $successmsg .= "<div class='alert alert-success'>Image - " . $userimage . " - Uploaded Successfully!</div>";

            }

        }   else {

              $error .= "Invalid File Format<br>";
            } 

        }   else { 

              $error .= "The Filename " . $_FILES["userimage"]["name"] . " already exists - please rename your picture before uploading<br>";
            }

    }
```

Comment: Have you checked which `$ext` this file has? Because you only accept certain extensions. Don't make any assumptions. You reject anything other than `"jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png" `, like, for instance: `"JPG"`.

Comment: "JPG" is not same as "jpg"

Comment: `$ext = pathinfo(strtolower($userimage), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` this will put all in small letters

Comment: It's always the little things, that solved the problem. Thanks